# $state.go won't change route in angular after confirmation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have this code to confirm navigation away in angular, using angular-ui router:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        //checks if campaign has been modified without save. 
        //if yes state change needs to be confirmed by modal
        //otherwise simple navigates away
        event.preventDefault();
        // var _this = this;
        _this.toState = toState;
        _this.toParams = toParams;

        var modalInstance = bootstrapModals.confirm({
            title: "Exit without saving?",
            message: "You have changes to the campaign. Leave without saving?"
        });
        modalInstance.then(function(result) {
            $state.go(_this.toState.name, _this.toParams);
        }, function(error) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

However $state.go only displays the modal again, without any route change. The values in _this.toState.name and _this.toParams are correct.

What's the issue?

Comment: Try removing the first `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: The route changes first and then displays the modal. Not good.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop on success. Every time you do a state change, you go back in the code causing the modal to be displayed again. You need to  save the answer to prevent the modal from popping back up.

Answer (score 1):

It was still listening to routeChange. So I had to do it like this:

```
onRouteChangeOff = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', routeChange);

    function routeChange (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        //checks if campaign has been modified without save. 
        //if yes state change needs to be confirmed by modal
        //otherwise simple navigates away

        // var _this = this;
        _this.toState = toState;
        _this.toParams = toParams;

        var modalInstance = bootstrapModals.confirm({
            title: "Exit without saving?",
            message: "You have changes to the campaign. Leave without saving?"
        });
        modalInstance.then(function(result) {
            //should stop listening to $stateChangeStart
            onRouteChangeOff ();
            $state.go(_this.toState.name, _this.toParams);
        }, function(error) {
            // event.preventDefault();
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to get home to post this, sorry.

I'm not sure if the ModalInstance will work the same way, but this is the code using good 'ol confirm:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    //checks if campaign has been modified without save. 
    //if yes state change needs to be confirmed by modal
    //otherwise simple navigates awa
    // var _this = this;
    _this.toState = toState;
    _this.toParams = toParams;

    var result = confirm('are you sure you want to leave unsaved?');
    if(!result) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Don't prevent it first and don't use `$state.go()` if succeeding, only prevent if false.

You should be able to try something like this with the bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
bootstrapModals.confirm({
        title: "Exit without saving?",
        message: "You have changes to the campaign. Leave without saving?",
        callback: function(result) {
            if(result) {
                //yes
            }else {
                //no
            }
        }
    });
```