# Angular ui-rotuer $state.go not changing state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a factory I have created that will check if a state change is happening and if a form is dirty. If the form is dirty a modal will appear similar to a confirm window. My issue is that the `$state.go()` is not working. I am at a loss as to why:

```
(function() {

    var checkStateChangeService = function ($rootScope, $modal) {

        var addCheck = function ($scope, form, $state) {

            var modalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
                };
            };

            var removeListener = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',  function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {


                if (form.$pristine) {
                    return;
                }


                event.preventDefault();
                var message = "There are unsaved changes, do you want to continue?";
                var title = "Unsaved Changes";

                var modalHtml = "<div class=\"panel\">\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<h4 class=\"center\" id=\"modalTitle\">" + title + "<\/h4>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<div class=\"small-12 columns\">\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<div class=\"modal-body\">" + message + "<\/div>";
                modalHtml += "<div class=\"button-box\">\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<button ng-click='ok()' class=\"tiny\">OK<\/button>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<button ng-click='cancel()' class=\"tiny\">Cancel<\/button>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<\/div>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<\/div>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<\/div>";

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    template: modalHtml,
                    controller: modalInstanceCtrl
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                    $state.go(toState);
                }, function () {
                    $state.go(fromState);
                });

            });

            $scope.$on("$destroy", removeListener);
        };

        return { checkFormOnStateChange: addCheck};
    }

    var module = angular.module("traApp");
    module.service("checkStateChangeService", checkStateChangeService);
}());
```

I am not seeing any errors and not sure why this is an issue. I have seen several examples very similar to mine.

Comment: `$state.go(toState)` seems to actually keep you in the current state only.

Comment: can you create sample on Plnkr.co to show your problem ?

Comment: @AvijitGupta, it shouldn't. Inspecting the the `toState` object, the name and url are correct. Also, I have tried using $state.go('some.state') and that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751541/state-go-wont-change-route-in-angular-after-confirmation) which helped me address the issue. The only small issue I see is that the modal closes after the state is changed. Kind of looks strange, but it works. [AvijitGupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4135178/avijit-gupta), actually made me think because it did seem like the state was not being changed.

```
(function() {

    var checkStateChangeService = function ($rootScope, $modal) {

        var addCheck = function ($scope, form, $state) {

            var _this = this;

            var modalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close();

                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
                };
            };

            var removeListener = function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {


                if (form.$pristine) {
                    return;
                }

                _this.toState = toState;
                _this.toParams = toParams;

                var message = "There are unsaved changes, do you want to continue?";
                var title = "Unsaved Changes";

                var modalHtml = "<div class=\"panel\">\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<h4 class=\"center\" id=\"modalTitle\">" + title + "<\/h4>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<div class=\"small-12 columns\">\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<div class=\"modal-body\">" + message + "<\/div>";
                modalHtml += "<div class=\"button-box\">\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<button ng-click='ok()' class=\"tiny\">OK<\/button>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<button ng-click='cancel()' class=\"tiny\">Cancel<\/button>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<\/div>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<\/div>\r\n";
                modalHtml += "<\/div>";

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    template: modalHtml,
                    controller: modalInstanceCtrl
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function () {

                    onRouteChangeOff();                    
                    $state.go(_this.toState.name, _this.toParams);
                }, function (error) {

                });

                event.preventDefault();
            };

            var onRouteChangeOff = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', removeListener);

       };

        return { checkFormOnStateChange: addCheck};
    }

    var module = angular.module("traApp");
    module.service("checkStateChangeService", checkStateChangeService);
}());
```